# Extension removal removes custom entity table

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

If a shopware 6 app is deleted and "Remove all app data permanently" is not enabled, it will keep the app configuration but it still deletes all custom entities (db tables) which are defined in the entities.xml.

My expectation was that if "Remove all app data permanently" is not enabled, that it keeps all app data, not only configuration data.

Is that a bug or a feature?

EDIT: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-26087

Comment: This sounds like a good question for Shopware's issue tracker

Comment: Does this happen for any app or only specific ones?

Comment: Well it is happening with my custom app i just released at shopware 6 store and also with a non published one which is in development.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the behavior you described is a feature.

When you delete a Shopware 6 app, the system will remove all the custom entities defined in the `entities.xml` file, as these are specific to the app and are not part of the shopware core. This is because custom entities are typically created to store app-specific data and are not part of the shopware database schema. So, deleting the app also removes the custom entities associated with it.

However, the app configuration settings are usually stored in the shopware database and these can be preserved even if the app is deleted. That is why you observed that the app configuration was still available even after the app was deleted.

Regarding the "Remove all app data permanently" option, if this option is enabled, it will delete all the data associated with the app, including the custom entities and the configuration settings. And so if you want to preserve the app data, it is important to disable this option before deleting the app.

In summary, it seems that is a feature.

Comment: i fully understand that, but the custom entities as you described yourself are getting deleted independelty of the status of "Remove all app data permanently"